# Bokeh Uncaught Error: property wasn't declared

Tags: python, bokeh, pythonanywhere

I have successfully deployed my Django app on PythonAnywhere.com except for my Bokeh plots. Instead of rendering, this is the error that shows up in the console.

```
bokeh-1.1.0.min.js:31 Uncaught Error: property Title.plot wasn't declared
at e.setv (bokeh-1.1.0.min.js:31)
at e [as constructor] (bokeh-1.1.0.min.js:31)
at e [as constructor] (bokeh-1.1.0.min.js:31)
at e [as constructor] (bokeh-1.1.0.min.js:31)
at e [as constructor] (bokeh-1.1.0.min.js:31)
at e [as constructor] (bokeh-1.1.0.min.js:31)
at new e (bokeh-1.1.0.min.js:31)
at Function.t._instantiate_object (bokeh-1.1.0.min.js:31)
at Function.t._instantiate_references_json (bokeh-1.1.0.min.js:31)
at Function.t.from_json (bokeh-1.1.0.min.js:31)
```

It works fine on LocalHost. Now that it is deployed, it throws up this error. I tried to read through the JS file itself, but am clueless.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using the same version (1.1.0) of Bokeh on both your localhost and PythonAnywhere?  The latest version is 1.2.

Comment: As the maintainer of Bokeh, it is better when for us when SO questions have accepted answers. Can one of you post the answer, and @AjayShah can you accept it?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue, but it turned out that the version of `bokeh` I was using was different from that required by the stylesheets and scripts I imported.

You can check the version of `bokeh` on the server using:

```
pythonX.Y
>>> import bokeh
>>> bokeh.__version__
```

where `X.Y` is the python version you selected for deployment.
After that, just install the required `bokeh` module using:

```
pythonX.Y -m install bokeh==<required version> --upgrade --user
```

(*Mentioning the python version is important.*)

Hope that helps!